# Flutter iOS FCM notifications onMessage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem trying to show onMessage notification on iOS, Android is working correctly. I send notification and the onMessage is trigered but not showing the Flushbar at it does on the Android device. The strange thing that in the console it prints the onMessage but it's not showing the Flushbar on the App.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        int idEvent = int.parse(message['data']['idevent']);
        String image = message['data']['image'];

        Flushbar(
          title: message['notification']['title'],
          message: message['notification']['body'],
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
          flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
          flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.GROUNDED,
          onTap: (Flushbar fb) async {
            fb.dismiss();

            ServiceEvent.fetchEvent(idEvent).then((event) {
              if (event != null) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EventDetailsPage(
                      event,
                      fromNotification: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                DialogUtility.dialogInfo(
                    context, "There was an error didn't find event");
              }
            }).catchError((error) {
              DialogUtility.dialogInfo(context, error.toString());
            });
          },
          icon: image != null
              ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                child: Image.network('$image', height: 40, width: 40,),
              )
              : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/tarjeta-rocket-entries.svg',
                    semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo',
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                ),
        )..show(buildContext);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        //_homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      //print('token: '+token);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noticied the problem.
The json is different from Android and iOS when receiving the onMessage notification and doesn't show any exception on the firebase onMessage.

Comment: true, above that, you have an example now :)

Answer (score 1):

App local notification works for me like this

```
 setUpLocalNotification() async {
    //Local Notification Configuration--------
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    //end local notification
  }
```

call the function in init state and then checked the os type and show notification.

```
 if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        message['aps']['alert']['title'],
        message['aps']['alert']['body'],
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: JsonEncoder.withIndent("    ").convert(message),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i have fixed this  by request permission while you initialize firebase masseging

```
if(Platform.isAndroid){
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!.requestNotificationsPermission();
}else {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!.requestPermissions();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Modify the upcoming json

```
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage");
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          message = _modifyNotificationJson(message);
        }
);
 /// This method will modify the message format of iOS Notification Data
  Map _modifyNotificationJson(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    message['data'] = Map.from(message ?? {});
    message['notification'] = message['aps']['alert'];
    return message;
  }
```